# Upload IPA, strange issue: ERROR ITMS-90032:“Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key '$key': '$path'

Tags: ios, xcode, upload

[image]

Hi everyone, there is a strange issue when I try to upload new build to iTunes Connect via Xcode. I think the problem with Info.plist file.

Info.plist: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Rp51VcZkP-uoUnaBwtr86EAPLLq-aN2w9f2CNrRZsBQ/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<string>Icon-Splotlight-iOS7.png</string>
<string>Icon-Splotlight-iOS7@2x.png</string>
```

Could be this typo for the Spotlight images.

Comment: Thanks very much! But Stackoverflow require more reputation to up vote... huhmmm

Comment: I believe clicking the tick beside the answer marks it as correct.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue, I was using **xcassets** for the icons and other images. I removed the icon-file entries in info.plist (CFBundleIconFiles & other) and it fixed the issue.

Comment: That solution worked for me on a Cordova project. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I tried to upload one of my clients app to AppStore. The projects AppIcon assets were in wrong dimensions. Then I have fixed the issue by putting the appropriate images for the correct dimensions. Viola ! the issue was fixed.