# ERROR ITMS-90391 Missing Icons for WatchKit

Tags: ios, watchkit, xcode9

I get an error when trying to submit my Apple Watch app to iTunes Connect.

[image]

Here are my icon set and setting.

[image]

Has anyone had the same issue? I had everything alright until updated to xcode9.

Comment: Did you add(updated) support for watchOS 4?  There should be something missing related to WatchOS 4 settings. Check all icon set and setup for watchOS 4.

Comment: This may help you - https://stackoverflow.com/q/28693546/5638630

Comment: I have checked all app icons are for "watchOS 2.0 and later", is anywhere else I should set for watchOS 4.0?